# Edit item under pushed ID from firebase through Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My goal is to edit the "price" under a pushed ID in my database. My current code does not let me edit it, but instead it creates another pushed ID. How do I edit it and not create not pushed ID? Thanks in advance.

This is my code for editing the data:

```
String uid = currentUser.getUid();

        prodidref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile").child(uid).child("Products");
        String prodid = prodidref.push().getKey();

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");
        profdb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile").child(uid).child("Products").child(prodid);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String keyprice = "price";
                String valueprice = ETPrice.getText().toString();
                DatabaseReference child = profdb.child(keyprice);
                child.setValue(valueprice);
            }
        });
```

Here's a screenshot from my database:

[image: screenshot]

This is the result of my current code:

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: it's happening because of .push() it will be push every time in new string random inside your firebase database ! String prodid = prodidref.push().getKey();

Comment: How do I avoid that then? Because I think I need the '.push()' in order to get the values under the pushed ID? @kdblue

Comment: wait i writing answer !

Comment: If you don't know the key of the product you want to modify, you will need to perform a query find that key. This means that you must know something about the product on which you can query.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ohhh okay I think I have an idea, you're right, I just realized that. Thanks.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen If I may ask, do you have a code that you can share as an answer to my problem?

Comment: I can definitely show some code, but only once I know what you're trying to update. Right now your question is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). **What** are you trying to accomplish? E.g. "I'm trying to add a price of 20 to Broccoli" is a goal. Then we know that `Broccoli` is the thing you know about the item you're looking to update, and can help you write the query (or point to the documentation that helps you towards that).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the `price` of `Broccoli` is the one I'm trying to update. I'm trying to add an _edit_ feature where my user could edit the price of his product (Broccoli). I'm quite having a hard time trying to write the query though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the key of the product you want to modify, you will need to perform a query find that key. This means that you must know something about the product on which you can query. E.g. if you're trying to set a price of 20 on Broccoli, you can run a query to find the Broccoli and update based on that:

```
DatabaseReference products = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");
Query broccolis = products.orderByChild("name").equalTo("Broccoli");
broccolis.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot broccoli: snapshot.getChildren()){
            broccoli.getRef().child("price").setValue(20);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException()l
    }
});
```

Comment: It's working now thanks to your code, I appreciate the help!

Comment: I have a follow up question. What if I want to update the price of another product? Will I create another activity for that? Or is there a simpler way for that? (because creating more activities would be stressful).

Comment: I'd expect that you start with an activity that list products. When the user selects one, you show an activity with details for that product. In those cases, you'd pass the key of the selected product from the first activity to the second.

Comment: How do I pass the key of the selected product from the first activity to the second?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you !

```
String uid = currentUser.getUid();

String pushKey;

        prodidref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile").child(uid).child("Products");
        String prodid = prodidref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                   Log.d("kkkk activelink",""+snapshot.getKey());

                   pushKey = snapshot.getKey();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        profdb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile").child(uid).child("Products").child(pushKey);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String keyprice = "price";
                String valueprice = ETPrice.getText().toString();
                DatabaseReference child = profdb.child(keyprice);
                child.setValue(valueprice);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What's the use of
`iCallBackActiveLink.activeLinkAct(activeLinkArrayList);`?

Comment: In the `pushKey = snapshot.getKey`, there's an error `Variable 'pushKey' is accessed from within inner class`

Comment: make it final !

Comment: I did and it returned `Cannot assign a value to final variable 'pushKey'`

Comment: okay can you do one thing, can you check what is printing in log cat ! , comment errors code , i want check it is giving your node value or not!

Comment: Can you try to do a query to find the key of the product instead?

Comment: what do you get?